# Managing temp files

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

I have a website developed with Django that deals with a big number of TIFF files which consist of a lot of layers.
In order to give the user the ability to browse the layers, I extracted the layer and saved them as JPEGs in a temp folder when the user chooses a TIFF file, and then he can browse all the layers.
The problem is that it is a bad idea to keep all the JPEGs stored for the next browsing request! Any suggestions to manage the extracted JPEGs when they are requested and then get rid of them?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [tempfile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html) library

```
import tempfile

with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as temp:
    temp.write('Some data')
    temp.flush()
```